# Problems with Cloud SDK

Tags: sdk, cloud, gcloud

So I am a complete noob and have no idea how to even navigate these forum as it all sound like a foreign language. My issue is I recent was accepted to use Google page speed service and cannot even get the first step out of the way which is installing Cloud SDK.

Here is step by step what I did:

1. Extracted all from zip file
2. Clicked to launch the Batched file (upon clicking the command prompt black screen flashed in the corner, no instructions or anything else)
3. When attempting to authenticate google cloud platform by clicking windows key + r. THen typing in 'gcloud auth login', I get a message that says, "cannot find 'gcloud'.....".

Comment: (1) StackOverflow is NOT a forum but a Question-Answer site (different format with different rules). (2) It's not clear from your text, what question you wanted to ask. "Help me" is not a question and such text is not suitable for StackOverflow. You can edit your post in order to actually ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you run install.bat, this is an interactive process that should not exit immediately.  I'm guessing you don't have Python installed?  Install Python 2.7 and try again.

After the installer runs, it will print directions on how to add gcloud to your PATH.  In general, though, gcloud is a command line tool that you shouldn't really run using windows+r.  It's best to open a cmd prompt so you can more easily run multiple commands.